# What does this Object class mean?

Tags: java, object

I just wanna know what does Object S[] mean in this code? This is a snippet of a source code for Stack in array. Is this a data type? What does it return? and what type of data should be entered?

```
public class ArrayStack implements Stack {

public static final int CAPACITY = 1000;
public int capacity;
Object S[];
```

Answer (score 0):

In answer to the titular question `Object S[];` is a declaration of an array of objects named `S`.

> What does it return?

Nothing. What does what return? You have given the start of a class's definition, so without closing it throws an error.

If you mean, "What does `Object S[];` return", again, nothing is returned because it is not an operation. https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/when-to-use-a-function-declarations-vs-a-function-expression-70f15152a0a0/

Please try and break your question down next time as each one is based on an increasingly fuzzy understanding of the answers to those it follows.

Answer (score 0):

`Object S[];` is just a variable declaration. The variable is called `S` and has type `Object[]`. You could also write it as `Object[] S;` for clarity.

It doesn't "return" anything, but `S` is an uninitialized array of `Object`. After initializing you can add any object to it.